# Javascript as response to controller action displays it's own code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, turbolinks

This is bugging me for already three days. I have a form which I submit and after that I inject javascript code into page depending about success of validation. My controller action is simple and it looks like this:

```
def create
    @cat = Cat.new(cat_params)
    @cat.save
end
```

Which triggers `create.js.erb`:

```
<% if @cat.new_record? %>
    $('#my_div').html('<%= j render('form') %>');
<% else %>
    $('#cats').append("done");
<% end %>
```

First line in `create.js.erb` checks if the cat is new record. If it is, it means validation failed and it renders a new form with validation errors. This is where I have a problem. The new form shows together with errors but when I try to submit a form again, it doesn't work and it just displays code of form on another page. So, imagine a completely blank page on which is displayed this code from `create.js.erb` in case of success:

```
$('#my_div').html('ALL CODE OF MY RE-RENDERED FORM. Really all source code of my form is displayed here with all tags and everything. Like javascript didn't insert anything.');
```

And in case of failure:

```
$('#cats').append("done");
```

Javascript code is not active at all. I have a remote form which is used for creation of new `cat` defined like this:

```
<%= form_for @cat, remote: true, format: 'js', method: 'post', :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
```

I am using jQuery-File-Upload for my form but it shouldn't be a problem in this case:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#new_cat').fileupload
    dataType: "script"
    add: (e, data) ->
      types = /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
      file = data.files[0]
      if types.test(file.type) || types.test(file.name)
        data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", file))
        $('#new_cat').append(data.context)
      else
        alert("#{file.name} is not a gif, jpeg, or png image file")

      $("#submit_button").on 'click', ->
        data.submit()

    progress: (e, data) ->
      if data.context
        progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
        data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%')
```

I really don't get it what could be a problem here. I am using turbolinks so maybe that could be a problem but I don't understand why javascript which is a response to certain action would not be translated. Any ideas what could be a problem?

Comment: Probably better to just send a success response with whatever data is needed. From your example, there's no good reason to be generating the JavaScript on the server anyway.

Comment: @Paul, Thanks! Then how can I trigger form validation and render uploaded object partial. I am uploading multiple files at the same time. Can you please give me a short sketch how would you do it :)

Comment: Clientside. Set the form(s) up either in the existing HTML of your page, or in a compiled template form, and then use a clientside template to fill out the details.  https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl if you're comfortable w/ jquery already.